# How to display calculated values in Drupal 8 views?

Tags: views, 8

Lets say I have an account field called **euro-budget**, and I have a content type **exchange rate** including the field **usd-value**" which import the USD exchange rate every 2 hours. In the view which displays all users including the field **euro-budget**. I want to have a calculated field which multiplies the field **euro-budget** with the latest **usd-value** field. What is the easiest way to do this? I already tried Views PHP but it is somehow not compatible with the latest **Drupal 8** version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [field formatter](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-field-formatter) for your euro-budget field and then select that for your field in your view.

Comment: thank you, I am slowly getting back on track with Drupal :)

Comment: Even better, install the drupal console and you can use that to generate the field formatter.  https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/en/commands/generate-plugin-fieldformatter.html